# WebMatrix Razor pages and global using statements

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, using, webmatrix

How can I setup global usings for all my .cshtml pages in WebMatrix Razor context (not ASP.NET MVC Razor)?

So instead of putting `@using System.Web.Optimization` on top of each .cshtml file where I need to include `@Scripts.Render()` I would put it into one single place instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.WebPages.WebPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

See also: [Building single-page app with AngularJS and ASP.NET MVC 4](http://tarkus.me/post/32121691785/angularjs-with-asp-net-mvc-4)

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**
Please take a look into the following posting. They discussing exactly your question, I am sure you can get the idea from there as to what to do:

[The name 'Assets' does not exist in the current context](http://forums.asp.net/t/1811979.aspx/1)

Hope this will help you

Comment: The answer from your link talks about Razor in ASP.NET MVC context and that's one is another story.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question, and edited the answer appropriately. Hope this helps better.

Comment: @GriefCoder was my response helpful? Can you mark it as right answer if so? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For webmatrix use the following in the web.config configuartion

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```